# Amazon turk - where does the data go?

Tags: mechanicalturk

Aloha - i would like to create an Amazon Turk task to collect information on hotel companies in Hawaii.

One quesion (that i was unable to get ansewred through the MTurk FAQ/website)

I have a form on my host that will allow the turkers to complete the task - can i re-direct or include this link in the task description. I tried creating a sample task - and it requires me to use/modify their existing DHTML template - and does not allow to re-direct to my data entry form hosted on my website. I was planning on providing detailed instructions on how to enter data into my site form on the MTurk task description.

Any help would be appreciated. Mahalo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need workers to fill out a form on your site you have two options:

1. Create your hits with an external question (requires use of the mturk API): http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSMechTurk/2008-02-14/AWSMechanicalTurkRequester/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html
2. Provide a link to workers to your form in the task description. When the worker has filled out your form, provide a verification code that they can enter into a field in your Mturk template. This way you can ensure the worker has completed your external form by checking that they entered a proper code.